# Client-side Javascript/JQuery Filtering w/ Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, frontend

New to jQuery and Javascript, but suppose I am currently returning a JSON of a QuerySet with the following fields (name, age, location) for a list of employees:

```
return render_to_response("index.html", {"employees": values}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

What is the correct way to write a drop down menu, which first lists only the different ages from the JSON (ie. 17, 30, 43, 45), and then renders a second drop down menu, which allows me to choose the names of employees who's age is greater than the age chosen in the first menu? I can do this by making additional requests, but I'm not sure how to do entirely on the client-side with js/jQuery. Furthermore, how would I dynamically change the second drop down menu without making any additional requests to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of employees, I think the preferred way is to make additional requests to the server, take a look at those links:

http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/

http://www.nerdydork.com/dynamic-filtered-drop-down-choice-fields-with-django.html